# how to add image to ::before pseudo element in css3

Tags: css, gravatar

I have an anchor with a data-avatar url that points to an image and I want to add a block image to a.avatar::before to show the image.

```
a[data-avatar]::before {
    content: "";
    background: url( attr(data-avatar url) ) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

<a href="/username" data-avatar="http://some-url.com/image.png">my profile</a>
```

I cannot set the background image with `url(attr(data-avatar))`

Here is a fiddle if anyone wants to take a stab -- I am only interested in CSS-only way of doing this without extraneous markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/RDrxV/

Comment: According to [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr), you could add a keyword to indicate the type of data. This way, you would get something like `url(attr(data-avatar url))`. However, I do not think this is supported very well (if at all).

Comment: I tried both url and string as 2nd argument, neither worked.

Comment: Support is probably limited to nonexistent. It's a nice experiment, but if you want it to actually work, you should probably choose a different approach (or use some JavaScript on top of it that forces webbowsers to "get it").

Comment: Yeah, it's more of a challenge than a necessity.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, as mentioned in the comments it is not possible with the current CSS2.1 implementation of `attr()` and `url()` to use an element's custom data attribute as an image URL in generated content.

It is not clear from [Values and Units level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr) whether you can/should pass `attr()` as an argument to `url()` (or if the grammar even allows it):

```
background: url(attr(data-avatar)) no-repeat 0 0;
```

or just pass `attr()` itself and it'll generate a URL value (this is more likely given they have a distinct `url` type from the default `string` type):

```
background: attr(data-avatar url) no-repeat 0 0;
```

But either way, as of 2012 no browser in existence has yet implemented the new `attr()` function, so you won't be able to do this with pure CSS generated content. Hopefully browsers will start implementing it now that the module has entered CR, because it'd be a huge shame to see this feature dropped due to lack of interest.

Comment: i believe it's a comma-separated list attr(data-avatar, url) -- but yes, it would be nice to be able to use data attributes in css.

Comment: @chovy: Doesn't seem so. The attribute name and type aren't separated by a comma, but what comes *after* that is comma-separated. It's strange why there's an inconsistency there...

Comment: Yeah you are right. MDN docs have it this way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/attr

Comment: It's also in the spec that I linked to.

Comment: I did some more research, and found bugs filed about this w/ mozilla. They won't fix, because it would be breaking the spec and thus require -moz-url() instead of url() to add support for attr(). I emailed w3c asking them to add it to spec.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've forgotten to add a content property. If it is absent then conent is not generated:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content

Just set it to an empty string.

```
a[data-avatar]::before {
    content:"";
    background: url(attr(data-avatar)) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: that doens't work. I don't think i can nest attr() inside url()

Comment: Indeed it's still not possible . Cf next answer